# Recursion: Frequency of digit in a scanned number: redux

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, java.util.scanner

I asked a similar question earlier today in regards to finding a type of digit (hard coded) in a number that was scanned in through text. I thought about if there was an input of what digit the user is looking for and started to research.  I can find plenty of "find frequency of all digits" but none about user input.  I understand converting int to string and counting characters, but I wanted to find another way of doing it, hopefully using recursion.

My main is set (I believe):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("countdigits.txt"));
    int Number = 0;
    int[] digit = new int [10];
    digit[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int remainder = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        Number = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Okay, which number (0-9) would you like to find?");
    digit = input.nextInt();
    try {
        if (digit < 0 || digit > 9) throw new IOException();

} catch (IOException f) {
    System.out.println("Funny.  Exiting");
    int Count = count(Number);

    System.out.format("** Number of digits in given number = %d", Count);
}
```

**edited to show progress**

```
private static int count(int number, int digit) {

return (number % 10 == digit ? 1 :0) + count(number / 10);
}
```

**I simplified the return to show the count, but now I have "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" error (2 ints in method, 1 in main). Can't figure out the call to input both integers and method into one variable.

Comment: Try to format your code properly. Your examples seem to miss a few `}`. You'll also have to pass the `digitArray` as parameter to your recursive function (unless its a field of the class).

Comment: thank you, i closed out properly.  I didn't finish digitArray. That's where i got stuck at, i.e. how to call and compare.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, how can i accurately get my method to compare inputted digit and compare to scanned in number and count the number of instances that digit occurs.

Comment: If your `count` method is supposed to work recursively you do not want to have a loop in it. Instead you'll need to decide whether to do another recursion or return your result. Also if you aim to count different digits your return can't be a single `int`.

Comment: Looks like you decided to only count one digit. Matching the argument lists should be trivial (pass along `digit`), but your still missing the condition to stop the recursion. Currently it would only result in an `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Do you really need to process these as numbers?  Your inputs are all Strings that you are converting to integers.  Then you are doing math to "scan" the digits in an integer.  It is easier to scan for characters in a String.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to convert the input from the file into a number at all.  You can scan the String for the char you need. Also I have shown it as a recursive function.

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("countdigits.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Okay, which number (0-9) would you like to find?");
            String digitInput = input.next();
            if (digitInput.length() != 1) {
                throw new IOException("only a single digit is allowed");
            }
            char targetDigit = digitInput.charAt(0);
            if (targetDigit < '0' || targetDigit > '9') {
                throw new IOException("only numbers are allowed");
            }

            int count = count(word, targetDigit, 0);
            System.out.format("** Number of digits in given number = %d", count);
        }

    } catch (IOException f) {
        System.out.println("Funny.  Exiting");
    }
}

private static int count(String word, char targetDigit, int targetStart) {
    int targetLoc = word.indexOf(targetDigit, targetStart);
    if (targetLoc < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + count(word, targetDigit, targetLoc + 1);
}
```